# "Draggable" Drag vertical only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable

I have this page that prompts you to drag it upwards to reveal the actual page. I want to know if there's any option so that you only can drag it vertically (Y-axis) i.e. "up". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using any plugins, f.ex jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, but only the jQuery and jQ UI libraries, but no other plugins.

Comment: Did you even glance at the API page for `Draggable`?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't see anything such as "Constraining Movement". And I also Googled it to see if any similar questions have been asked but I did not see any.

Comment: @ModernDesigner: And yet, "constrain" is *exactly* the word they use in the description of the option.

Comment: I knew to use "constrain" because @techfoobar already answered my question.

Comment: @ModernDesigner did you google "[draggable Y-axis](https://www.google.com/search?q=draggable%20Y-axis)"? Because I got plenty of suggestions and docs from the first results page :)

Comment: @David No... I googled "How to drag element vertical only jquery". As you can see there are a couple options where I could have found "Constrain Movement", but I wouldn't have known to look for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
```

Check this: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery UI, there is an [`axis`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-axis) option:

```
$(elem).draggable({ axis: 'y' });
```